# Can I use 'git push -f' to overwrite a commit already merged into a remote master?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to change the author of a single commit that I merged into a remote master.  Is it possible to just make the edit locally to that branch, squash the commits, and then `git push -f` will update the remote master?

If yes, do I need the proper privileges to force push master to do this, or is this allowed as long as the commit already has been merged into master?

If no, what is a good method for making a simple edit to a commit that's already been merged into a remote master?

Comment: It depends on the configuration and the rules you and your collaborators follow. By force-pushing, you can overwrite someone else's work, so it's usually not recommended. It might be possible to do it, but first make absolutely sure everyone is in sync.

Comment: Just fix it in a new commit. Don't worry about having too many commits. The advantage is your commit message makes it clear what changed

Comment: @osowskit I'm trying to change the author of the commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is possible to force push and overwrite tree with different history. However modifying history that is already on the master branch (or any other branch that is used by other people) is not recommended approach. If you need to fix the code, you can do it in the new, separate commit with a proper description what was broken and why the fix is needed.